# Store a dataURL in MongoDB to access it via local URL (JS)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, image, reactjs, meteor

So I don't know if my title is clear enough, what I want to do is, in my Meteor App, to have a tool that upload a file into my MongoDB, and output an URL that I could use it for example to display as the src of an 
Yet, I create my Collection:

```
export const Files = new Mongo.Collection('files');
```

and a addFile function :

```
export const addFile = (nameArg: String, dataURL: String) => {
 Files.insert({
  _id: uuid(),
  name: nameArg,
  url: dataURL
 });
console.log("file "+nameArg+" added");
};
```

Then I use the `react-jsonschema-form` package to display a file form

```
<Form
  schema={{
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
       file: {
         type: 'string',
         title: 'Upload an image to get its URI'
         }
       }
  }}
  uiSchema={{
    file: {
       'ui:widget': 'file'
    }
  }}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  liveValidate
  >
  <div />
</Form>
```

My onChange function :

```
onChange = (e: { formData: { file: string } }) =>{
  const [dataType, nameBis,] = e.formData.file.split(';');
  const name = nameBis.split('=')[1];
  Promise.resolve().then(addFile(name, e.formData.file));

}
```

And I'd like to use an address sush as `window.location.host+'/file/'+name`
to be able to use this image.
I believe it to be possible, but how ?

Thanks for all responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very much possible and in a secure way using packages `cfs:standard-packages` and `cfs:filesystem`. Frankly speaking, I did not go in depth for your question.

It is a beautiful package. You can read about above [here packages in depth](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/filesystem).

**CODE TO CREATE FILESYSTEM COLLECTION**

```
var imageStore = new FS.Store.FileSystem("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME");

YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME = new FS.Collection("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME", {
  stores: [imageStore]
});
```

In Short. The files will be saved at the sibling to `bundle/` location at `cfs/files/YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME`. Information about the file will be saved in the collection `cfs.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.filerecord` and temporary location will be used for internal purpose with collection `cfs._tempstore.chunks` as below.

If you save any file using above package. The metadata will be saved inside the `cfs.YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.filerecord` as below

```
{
    "_id" : "TBmxbsL2cMCM2tEc7",
    "original" : {
        "name" : "photo.jpg",
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-06T12:54:50.115Z"),
        "size" : 2261,
        "type" : "image/jpeg"
    },
    "uploadedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-08T06:58:32.433Z"),
    "copies" : {
        "YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME" : {
            "name" : "photo.jpg",
            "type" : "image/jpeg",
            "size" : 2261,
            "key" : "YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME-TBmxbsL2cMCM2tEc7-photo.jpg",
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-07-08T06:58:32.475Z"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-07-08T06:58:32.475Z")
        }
    }
}
```

at Client side, you can get the link to the document file using

`YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.find({"_id" : "TBmxbsL2cMCM2tEc7"}).url();`

This url is token based safe link to the file instead of direct location to your server. You can set additional allow/deny settings for download ans stuff just like normal collections. Hope this helps!

Comment: The thing is that with my code I already have the full image as a dataURL in base64, so I'd like like to just store it in a small fs. I've looked at the cfs:* docs and I'm having trouble for the inserting step because I'm defining my form as a react.component in a .jsx file so in my onChange function the data is contained in event.formData.file as a base64.

Comment: It does not matter whether you use react or blaze. Just assign that file to ` FS.File` instance, and them this instance to File collection and you are done. It is that easy.

Comment: Ok, problem solved, the `.url()`didn't work but because of the way cfs:filesystem place the uploaded files I coud resolve it to `window.location.origin+'/cfs/files/uploads/'+fileObj._id`. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure helping you!