# Meteor , read an image stored on server outside public folder

Tags: image, meteor, upload

i can't resolve image file's path on my server from my meteor app to use it as a source of my image tag , also i don't want to put it in public folder as it refreshes due to meteor watching with every image upload.

Comment: I have already answered this in other post. [Please click here to read here in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017531/store-a-dataurl-in-mongodb-to-access-it-via-local-url-js/45017830#45017830)

Comment: Then you can up vote it if  you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use [Meteor-files](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files). This packages allow you to insert file in your database. also you can work another thing with this packages